# Math kerning for entire document

Tags: math-mode, spacing, kerning, letterspacing, math-fonts

My question today is: How can I adjust the kerning for the math environment of the entire document? I am aware of the typical ways to add space, including `\,` etc., but I was hoping to make the spaces a tiny bit bigger across the entire document. I've created a new command that is the equivalent of `\kern 0.115em` and this seems to be about the right amount. Rather than insert this in all the necessary places, I'd rather just make the math do it by default in between each object if possible. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You don't give much information about where you want to add extra spacing. You can customise the spaces that Tex adds, notably `\medmuskip` around binary relations and `\thickmuskip` around relations are user-setable, however TeX adds no space between ordinary symbols, adjacent letters are usually further apart in math fonts due to the sidebearings in the font, but changing that requires changing the font metrics.

[image]

This shows text italic, math italic with normal spacing and the same math with increased spacing around relations and binary operators.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\textit{abc}+\textit{xyz}=123

\bigskip

$abc+xyz=123$

\bigskip
\medmuskip=10mu
\thickmuskip=20mu

$abc+xyz=123$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, unfortunately the problem is mostly between the adjacent letter and, for some reason, it's especially a problem with indices, exponents, and punctuation (namely, comma). It feels very bunched up and i was hoping i could "spread" things out. I know there are inter-word spacing commands like ``` \fontdimen2 ``` but I need something along the lines of intraword spacing for a math environment

Comment: @makala as I say the inter-letter spacing is a property of the font not of tex